# How to retain selected option after form submit in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a fixed option dropdownlist on my html page. It contains three options (By name, By Views, By Likes) for sorting the data displayed on page. When the value in the dropdown is changed, I am submitting the form and controller returns the updated data according to sort choice selected. But the selected option in dropdown resets to first option. How do I set the selected option in the dropdown.

I need to submit the form and do not send the ajax request.

Comment: ideally an ajax request would be best for this kind of thing, but you can also store your selected value in a ViewBag while returning the sorted results and in the document.ready event in jquery, set the value back in the dropdown. i know this is not neat but if you don't want to use Ajax, then this is what you can do.

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of attaching a .change() function attached to the dropdownlist in JQuery??
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @greendave11 even if he uses the jquery change() event, he'll still have to send the request to the server and he doesn't want to use Ajax.

Comment: If Saurabh stays on the client side and runs pure JQuery (on top of the ASP.net), they should not need to trigger the Ajax calls.  So a good place to start would be to have a function in the document load to attach just a console.log call to see what information is available

Comment: @Saurabh, you should post your view code so it can be answered that would fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks guys for reply.
@Sushil I did the same thing. But its not working. Below is the jquery code -    
    var SelectedOrderBy = '@ViewData["orderBy"]';
          
    if(SelectedOrderBy != "")
    {
        $('select[name="options"]').find('option[value="'+ SelectedOrderBy   +'"]').attr("selected","selected");
    } 

Can you please let me know whats wrong in this script?

Comment: what value are you getting for SelectedOrderBy?? if it is not empty, can you try $('#YourDropDownList').val(SelectedOrderBy); also I hope you're writing this in the $(document).ready

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the code. I was doing it but 5 minutes timeout happened and I am not able to edit it now..:(

Comment: That works!! Thank you all for the help!! 
I was getting correct values in that js variable. But the script for setting those value was wrong.

Comment: do you want me to post this as an answer and you can mark it then.

Comment: @Sushil sure, you can post it

Comment: posted my answer @Saurabh. please mark it as an answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `.val()` to set the selected value in the dropdown list.
try this `$('#YourDropDownList').val(SelectedOrderBy);`

Answer (score 1):

If you have some java script wired up to the change event of the drop down and you are calling `form.submit()` there, It is same as you submit your form with a submit button( Your page is getting a response from server).

You need to make sure that your view model has a property which can hold what was the selected item in the dropdown.

Have a view model like this

```
public class CriteriaVM
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SortItems { set; get; }
    public String SelectedSortItem { set; get; }

    public CriteriaVM()
    {
        this.SortItems=new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

So now in your GET action method, You are loading the `SortItems` collection and rendering that in your view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new CriteriaVM {SortItems = GetItems()};
    return View(vm);
}

private List<SelectListItem> GetItems()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "Name", Text = "Name"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "City", Text = "City"}
    };
}
```

and your view is

```
@model YourNameSpaceHere.CriteriaVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedSortItem,Model.SortItems,"Select")
    <input type="submit" />
    <div>Selected  : @Model.SelectedSortItem</div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Assuming jQuery library is included in the page
    $(function() {
       //whenever user changes the drop down,submit the form
        $("#SelectedSortItem").change(function() {
            $("#SelectedSortItem").closest("form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in the HttpPost action, make sure that you are setting the `SelectedSortItem` property explicitly after loading the `SortItems` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CriteriaVM model)
{
    var selected = model.SelectedSortItem;
    model.SortItems = GetItems();
    model.SelectedSortItem = selected;

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way is also correct. But as my drop down options were fixed and was noe going to change further, I choose to handle it through jquery only. But thanks for the crystal clear explanation!